# How to apply tax, discount to invoice using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to apply Tax, discount to subtotal and calculate grand total??

I have these paragraphs with the following ID's

```
<p id="subtotal">15000</p>
<p id="tax">10</p> // In percentage
<p id="discount">1000</p>
<p id="grandtotal"></p> // Grandtotal will be calculated and displayed here using jquery
```

The grand total would be 15000 + (1500 //tax) - (1000 //discount) = 15500

How do i calculate this using jQuery?

Comment: The equation you provided is a little confusing. Care to elaborate on it a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var subtotal = parseFloat( $('#subtotal').text());
var taxRate = parseFloat( $('#tax').text());
var disc = parseFloat( $('#discount').text());

var taxAmount = subtotal * (taxRate/parseFloat("100")); //15000 * .1

var yourGrandTotal = subtotal + (taxAmount) - (disc);

//update div with the val
$('#grandtotal').text(yourGrandTotal);
```

Comment: Thank you :) Exactly what i was looking for, though other answers are correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
var subtotal = parseFloat( $('#subtotal').text() );
...

$('#grandtotal').text( grandTotal );
```

The rest is vanilla javascript, other than setting or getting.

Answer (score 0):

First off, total abuse of the paragraph element `<p>`. Instead, use the folling:

HTML

```
<div id="subtotal-and-taxes">
    <var id="subtotal">15000</var>
    <var id="tax">10</var> // In percentage
    <var id="discount">1000</var>
    <var id="grandtotal"></var> // Grandtotal will be calculated and displayed here using jquery
    <!-- or use span elements -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#subtotal-and-taxes var {
    display:block
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Next, you can use jQuery to get references to those elements and read their contents with the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
var subtotal = $("#subtotal-and-taxes #subtotal").html();
var tax = $("#subtotal-and-taxes #tax").html();
var discount = $("#subtotal-and-taxes #discount").html();
```

and then use non-jQuery JavaScript to calculate the value for `grandtotal`. Unfortunately, your equation is a little confusing so I won't spell it out for you.